# 2005 Peugeot 206 has hard shifts and a P1167 DTC

Tags: transmission, peugeot

My friend's 2005 Peugeot 206 is experiancing hard shifting and sometimes lack of power starting out, which get's better as speed increases.

I hooked up my scan tool and found that it had a P1167 DTC.  The only thing I was able to find so far on this was this page:  [AL4 Pressure Regulation Fault](http://www.peugeotlogic.com/workshop/wshtml/transmis/al4/solenoid.htm):

> In most cases the transmission will go into the downgraded mode, or limp home. In this mode the transmission is locked in third speed to enable to continue the operation of the vehicle. This is reported by some drivers as a loss of power. The downgraded mode can be preceded by some very harsh up or down shifts. After stopping and restarting the engine, the transmission will usually return to normal operation.

This perfectly describes the problem.  There are a number potential problems listed.  Assuming that this is not just a bad pressure sensor, I was thinking of dumping some Lucas Transmission Fix in since that's supposed to help with solenoid pressure problems from what I've read.

The thing is, the car isn't worth much, and it's probably not worth enough to start opening up the tranny and working on it unless it's something really simple.  Am I completely wasting my time with this idea, or do I have a decent chance this might help?

**EDIT Feb. 28th 2017**

So I told the guy to take it to an official Peugeot guy and have them take a look at it.  They said the problem is with the valve body and insufficient ATF pressure.  So I'm going to throw in some Lucas and see if that helps as the person doesn't want to invest in the vehicle.  I'll update with results at some point.

Comment: Is the car equipped with manual or automatic transmission?

Comment: @SteveMatthews Automatic AL4 transmission.  Robotic actually I think, you can just put it in drive, or shift manually, but there's no clutch.

Comment: It would be worth checking in the system uses any hydraulics.

Comment: Just to update this car went to the junkyard